Unresponsive GUI - dual Nvidia GPU
I recently installed a second RTX 3090 Ti GPU into my system and Ubuntu 23.10 cannot handle that change.
Whenever I start the system the GUI is unresponsive and every 5-10 seconds or so one of the screens dims a little and lights up again (as if it was switching monitors or something). It goes on for 5 to 10 minutes and after that the UI starts working.
I reinstalled the NVidia drivers but it didn't help at all.
nvidia-smi -L

returns
GPU 0: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 Ti (UUID: GPU-3c8bf8c1-301a-29b8-eddb-2f13f2be7589)
GPU 1: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 Ti (UUID: GPU-1fca23d8-0d64-e1c9-e867-236667f55946)

and
lspci | grep VGA

returns
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3090 Ti] (rev a1)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3090 Ti] (rev a1)
17:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raphael (rev cb)

I have this problem only on Ubuntu. I have a dual boot system and Windows 11 works fine.
I also suspect that maybe the integrated graphics is being utilized because the UI doesn't work too fast, especially typing in the terminal comes with a lag.
How to fix that?
